# What source contains a vehicle made from a dead beholder?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, dnd-3e, product-identification, vehicles

A vehicle created from the corpse of a beholder, with the main eye and organs removed to make room for a pilot's seat, was published somewhere in 3.5 or 3ed Dungeons & Dragons. Does anyone know the source?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## That's a *beholder globe*

The *Dragon* #331 article "Fast, Furious, and Fantastical" by Frank Brunner includes the ***beholder globe***, a 120,000-gp vehicle made from a hollowed-out preserved beholder corpse, with some of the less powerful eye rays continuing to function under the pilot's control. The illustration by either Marc Sasso or Chris Trevas or both in collaboration is particularly evocative. With AC 20, hp 65, and hardness 10, it's pilot should be able to use it to terrorize several thorps before it's destroyed by intrepid PCs.